# ambiguous errorr due to reference microsoft.office.interop.excel

Tags: c#, reference, export-to-excel

I added a reference 'microsoft.office.interop.excel'
when i  add this reference i got an error that says
'button is ambiguous reference between 'system.windows.forms.button' and 
'microsoft.office.interop.excel'

my code contains the following function.

```
 using microsoft.office.interop.excel

 void SetButtons(Button i_InFrontButton)
 {
  ...
 }
```

Comment: I suspect your code doesn't *really* contain that using directive, all in lower-case with no semi-colon... and I suspect your *real* error message doesn't look like that either. Please copy and paste the *actual* code and error message.

Comment: Additionally - what kind of button *do* you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors says what is all about:

you have 2 namespaces available in yuour project

- microsoft.office.interop.excel
- system.windows.forms

both of them contain inside `Button` class, which is completely different one from another. 
So compiler looking on written `Button`, has no idea what should be chosen.

In this case, you have to specify fully qualified name of the type you intend to use, like:

```
 void SetButtons(System.Windows.Forms.Button i_InFrontButton)
 {
  ...
 }
```

or if you would like to have short notion of namespace (alias), you can define it in the beginning of the file like:

```
 using WF = Sytem.Windows.Forms; 
 ... 

 //so your function definition will look like
 void SetButtons(WF.Button i_InFrontButton)
 {
  ...
 }
```

Comment: Or use an alias, which may be a better idea if it's going to come up multiple times...

Comment: @JonSkeet: was writting that actually :)

Comment: You want to get rid of the "namespace" part in that example, and change the order. Also consider an example of `using WFButton = System.Windows.Forms.Button`...